# Перелив из одного цвета в другой. QPushButton

Tags: qt

Для примера приведу браузера Google Chrome. Когда мы наводим курсор на вкладку, видно (слабовато), как он постепенно становится серой, быстро конечно, но плавно, а когда убираем курсор, вновь приобретает белый цвет. Как реализовать примерно также для `QPushButton` (то есть плавный переход в другой цвет при наведении мыши на кнопку, и также наоборот, когда убираю курсор) в `Qt`? Наверно через `setStyleSheet`, но я вот не силен в CSS и HTML, а в интернете только для браузеров.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Определим новый класс-наследник `ChromeButtom` от `QPushButton`. Внутри определим новое свойство `background` в макросе `Q_PROPERTY`, там же укажем ему сеттер и геттер. Свойство необходимо для работы класса `QPropertyAnimation`, который, как понятно из названия, занимается плавным изменением одного значения свойства в другое, или анимацией.

```
class ChromeButtom : public QPushButton
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QColor background
               READ getBackground
               WRITE setBackground
               )
    QColor background;
    QPropertyAnimation anim;

public:
    explicit ChromeButtom(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ChromeButtom(const QString& text, QWidget *parent = nullptr);

    QColor getBackground() const;
    void setBackground(const QColor& back);

protected:
    void leaveEvent(QEvent *event);
    void enterEvent(QEvent *event);
};
```

Реализация сеттера и геттера для свойства `background`:

```
QColor
ChromeButtom::
getBackground() const {
    return background;
}

void
ChromeButtom::
setBackground(const QColor &back) {
    background = back;
    //установка цвета фона через qss (таблица стилей qt)
    this->setStyleSheet(QString{"background-color: rgb(%1, %2, %3);"}.arg(back.red()).arg(back.green()).arg(back.blue()));
}
```

В конструктор добавить код

```
setBackground(QColor(Qt::gray)); //текущий цвет фона
anim.setPropertyName("background"); //свойство для анимации
anim.setTargetObject(this); //свойство какого объекта
anim.setDuration(200); //продолжительность смены
anim.setStartValue(QColor(Qt::gray)); //из какого цвета
anim.setEndValue(QColor(Qt::white));  //в какой
```

Переопределённые функции событий входа\выхода курсора мыши в пределы виджета:

```
void
ChromeButtom::
enterEvent(QEvent *) {
    //начать анимированную смену свойства background
    anim.setDirection(QAbstractAnimation::Forward);
    anim.start();
}

void
ChromeButtom::
leaveEvent(QEvent *) {
    //начать анимированную смену свойства background в обратном направлении
    anim.setDirection(QAbstractAnimation::Backward);
    anim.start();
}
```